# how to install connector/j on windows 7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been working on installing Connector/J on my computer, but I can't make it work. There are some problems I encounter along the way. Here is what I did:

(based on what I read in the internet)

First I downloaded *mysql-connector-java-5.0.8*. After extracting it, I guess I am supposed to put `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` where my classpath is. Here I have a problem, after installing java jdk v8, I don't get any variable called classpath in my environment variable. So how am I supposed to put it somewhere without knowing where?

I read in the net that I should put it in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext`

And then I have to set the classpath variable accordingly. I created a new variable and set it with variable name : `classpath` and variable value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext`

After running my program in Netbeans (the program is supposed to connect to a database) I get this error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306

Which is for the line that I am trying to get a connection :

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "reza", "reza" );
```

I really have no idea what is happening here. I am lost, I searched over and over again but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Try again.. On you program (On netbeans) click on Library directory -> add Jar/folder  -> Browse to your mysql driver. Then clean and build again ! Hope to help !

Comment: Never ever install something into `lib\ext`; this is not what it was intended for, and it will be removed in future Java versions.

Comment: Also note that mysql connector/J 5.0.8 is **very old**. Your attempt to set the classpath fails because most methods of executing java applications **don't use it**.

Comment: hi CodeMonster , thanks for the help , what do you mean by clean and build again ? you mean now that i have set my classpath then i should copy  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar there? am i right ?

Comment: Hi mark , thanks for the reply , you said that mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 is very old , but this is the latest version available i believe , so what should i do?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ latest version: 5.1.36